# Multiple Associations to the Same Model in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, model-associations, belongs-to

I am using cakePHP version 3.x.

When i query the MessagesTable i want to get the Users data for the the sender and the receiver of the message. I have done this many times in cakePHP 2 but i cant figure out why it isn't working in version 3.x.

i have a UsersTable and a MessagesTable.

UsersTable

```
$this->hasMany('Messages');
```

MessagesTable

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'sender_id',
    'propertyName' => 'Sender',
]);
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'propertyName' => 'Receiver'
]);
```

This is the query i am using

```
$messages = $this->Messages->find()
        ->where(['Messages.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
        ->orwhere(['Messages.sender_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
        ->order(['Messages.created' => 'DESC'])
        ->contain([
            'Users.Pictures',
        ]);
```

I am getting the Receiver data back but not the Sender data as well. Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your associations are wrong. If using the same model for multiple associations you need to use different aliases and the `className` property (just like in CakePHP 2):-

```
$this->belongsTo('Sender', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'sender_id',
    'propertyName' => 'sender',
]);
$this->belongsTo('Receiver', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'propertyName' => 'receiver'
]);
```

This is [described in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#associations-linking-tables-together).

In your example code `Receiver` is overwriting the association for `User` so you only see the `Receiver` model in the results.

Your query then needs to be something like:-

```
$messages = $this->Messages->find()
    ->where(['Messages.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
    ->orwhere(['Messages.sender_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
    ->order(['Messages.created' => 'DESC'])
    ->contain([
        'Receivers' => ['Pictures'],
        'Senders' => ['Pictures']
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @drmonkeyninja. Your suggestion was the first thing i tried but that gave me an error saying Messages is not associated with Users even though they are associated, which lead me to believe i was doing it wrong in cakePHP 3 so that's why i changed it. Any ideas as to why its giving that error?

Comment: @Wisd0m is your Users model in a plugin?

Comment: no my Users model isn't in a plugin. Its really strange that its giving me that error, could it have something to do with the Users hasMany('Messages') relationship?

Comment: @Wisd0m if you're not using a plugin why have you got `contain(['Users.Pictures'])`? I wouldn't have thought the Users hasMany('Messages') relationship should matter as you are querying from the Messages model.

Comment: I was using contain(['Users.Pictures']) to get the user data and user picture for each message. If i remove the contains i no longer get the user data as the multiple Messages belongsTo() isnt working.

Comment: Is Pictures a model belonging to Users?

Comment: Yes Pictures is a model that belongsTo the Users model.

Comment: Your `contain` parameters look wrong. I've updated my answer with what I believe should be the query. Your error is probably occurring as you are referencing the `Users` model when your associations are `Senders` and `Receivers`.

Comment: It is worth nothing that the Cake convention for `propertyName` is to use the lower-case underscored singular version of the model name.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help @drmonkeyninja. I have found what was wrong, all i needed to do was call the Users associations i defined in the MessagesTable, i feel so stupid now.

MessagesTable

```
$this->belongsTo('Sender', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'sender_id',
    'propertyName' => 'Sender',
]);
$this->belongsTo('Receiver', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'propertyName' => 'Receiver'
]);
```

The query that works:

```
$messages = $this->Messages->find()
        ->where(['Messages.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
        ->orwhere(['Messages.sender_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
        ->order(['Messages.created' => 'DESC'])
        ->contain([
            'Sender',
            'Receiver'
        ])
    ;
```