# Multiple relations to the same model in CakePHP version 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, model-associations

This question is in relation to an existing question on [Multiple relations to the same model CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844998/multiple-relations-to-the-same-model-cakephp), which was focusing on cakephp version 2. 
This question is looking for a similar solution to define multiple relations to the same model for cakephp version 3?

**Here is what I tried:**
For this example imagine, you have a model 'Matches'. In the match you have a home-team and an guest-team competing against each other. Teams are stored in model 'Teams'. You will need two associations to the Team model, one for home and one for guest team. This is what is defined in the Match model:

```
$this->belongsTo(
    'HomeTeam', [

        'className' => 'Team',
        'foreignKey' => 'home_team_id',
        'propertyName' => 'HomeTeam'
    ],
    'GuestTeam', [
        'className' => 'Team',
        'foreignKey' => 'guest_team_id',
        'propertyName' => 'GuestTeam'
        ]    
    );
```

**Here is the issue:**
However when using this, cake does not seem to recognize the Home-Team and Guest-Team and complaints about missing association to table Teams.

**The question:**
Is there anything wrong in the way how I defined this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3 Multiple BelongsTo Associations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928324/cakephp-3-multiple-belongsto-associations)

Comment: You mention it looking for table "Account", but that's not in your question anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks - error on my side - corrected.

Comment: Not sure why you think you can pass four arguents to `belongsTo`; that should be two separate calls. If that doesn't fix it, show us the query that's causing the error.